# unicorn can't restart because `parse_rackup_file': rackup file (master) not readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn, rackup

After I execute `kill -9 pid_of_unicorn` command for my unicorn instance, I can never restart it. I use `unicorn master -c config/unicorn.rb` in rails app root path and the unicorn.rb file which is my unicorn config file in the rails's config directory.

```
/home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:659:in `parse_rackup_file': rackup file (master) not readable (ArgumentError)
  from /home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:77:in `reload'
  from /home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
  from /home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
  from /home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
  from /home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
  from /home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  from /home/wujing/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Anybody experienced a similar problem?

Comment: What is `master` in your command

Comment: Try: `bundle exec unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb`

Comment: Thank you very much ! I copy from `ps -aux | grep unicorn ` output  directly, the right command is `unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> unicorn master -c config/unicorn.rb

Not sure what `master` means in your command. This is what you can try:

```
bundle exec unicorn -D -E <environment> -c config/unicorn.rb
```